# R script in batch mode -- Echoing messages to windows shell

Tags: windows, r, shell

I have an R script which is to be run in batch mode from a Windows shell and I need to "echo" messages to this shell.

A combination of `R CMD BATCH myscript.R con` and `options(echo=FALSE)` is not really an option since I also need to generate an .Rout file with all the commands and outputs.

I have also tried `shell("echo Some text")` to no avail.

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show us an example script? Calling `shell` from an R script that you're running with `R CMD BATCH` seems like a very strange idea. I imagine you just want to populate your code with standard errors/warnings/messages.

Comment: By "windows shell" do you mean from a command-line window?

Comment: If my guess is correct, `shell("echo Some test > CON")` should work.

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks! Care to make an answer of it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send text directly to the console window (rather than the standard output) using the CON device.

In your case, this would be

```
shell("echo Some text > CON")
```